# Memory Exception using realm

Tags: android, realm

I am getting memory exception anonymously, i don't know which block of code causes it. but i know its from realm. Is it because i'm using single insert instead of bulk insert.

```
realm.beginTransaction();
summary = realm.createObject(ActivitySummary.class);
JSONObject activity = activities.getJSONObject(i);
JSONArray datas;
summary.setActID(activity.getInt("actID"));
summary.setActName(activity.getString("actName"));
summary.setSourceID(activity.getString("sourceID"));
datas = activity.getJSONArray("data");
for (int j = 0; j < datas.length(); j++) {
    JSONObject data = datas.getJSONObject(j);
    Date endTime = !data.getString("endTime").equals("null") ? new Date(data.getLong("endTime")) : new Date();
    summary.setEndTime(endTime);
    summary.setLogID(data.getString("logID"));
    summary.setDate(data.getInt("date"));
    summary.setStartTime(!data.getString("endTime").equals("null") ? new Date(data.getLong("startTime")) : new Date());
    summary.setValue(data.getString("value1"));
    summary.setValue2(data.getString("value2"));
    realm.commitTransaction();
}
```

Exception `12-23 10:40:10.302: A/libc(13101): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xd1d1d1cd (code=1), thread 13101 (com.lifestyle) –`

Comment: Please post the stack trace.

Comment: 12-23 10:40:10.302: A/libc(13101): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0xd1d1d1cd (code=1), thread 13101 (com.lifestyle)

Comment: Is that the only information available? No deeper stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug in the above code. A beginTransaction() must have a matching commitTransaction() and vice versa. It is recommended to use executeTransaction() to ensure that. So you either have to move the beginTransaction() inside the loop or the commitTransaction() outside the loop. It's not entirely clear if that's your memory problem though.

Comment: actually the commit was outside the loop.. but still i was getting this error

Comment: im trying to close the realm instance but no close method available for realm instance

Comment: In the latest version there certainly is a "close()" method on the realm instance returned from getInstance(). Are you using the latest version?

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need to close your Realm instances by calling realm.close()

If you are using Realm on multiple threads, than you might have stumbled on Realm.io bug where it was sending update notification messages to dead threads/Realms.

It had been fixed in version 0.76.0 by adding this piece of code in close() method:

```
if (handler != null) {
    handlers.remove(handler);
}
```

Updating to newest version fixed this same error for me.

You need to keep track of all your Realm.getInstance() and realm.close() - they have to be called exactly same  number of times for each thread. Even though the Realm object itself is only one per thread, calling getInstance() iterates it's ref counter by one, and close() decreases ref counter by one. Realm will be dismissed when ref counter gets to 0.